# setuptools package requiring allow-unverified git repos

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setuptools

How do I allow for external requirements in my setup.py?

eg:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['some_package',]
    dependency_links=['git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/some/repo.git#egg=some_package'],
    ...
)
```

this fails with:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement some-package in /home/myhome/Envs/some_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from asdf==0.1.0)
Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified some-package to allow).
```

add `--allow-all-external` and `--allow-unverified some-package git+ssh://...` to the requirements.txt and install with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it works.

However, I cannot get it to work in setup.py